# Função onClick não funciona adequadamente

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma aplicação bem simples em que desejo mudar a cor do texto ao clicar no botão. Sendo que quero tratar o evento onClick diretamente no arquivo .js, não no HTML. Alguém poderia apontar o que está errado no meu código?
OBS: Todos os arquivos se encontram no mesmo diretório.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>JS - Change Color</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="header">Click to change the color!</h1>
    <input type="button" id="colorButton" value="Click me!"></input>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
.red-text {
    color: red;
}
```

### Javascript

```
var colorButton = document.getElementById('colorButton');

colorButton.onClick = function () {
    console.log('clicked');
    header.className = 'red-text';
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está na forma como foi escrito o [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick).

O erro ocorre pois o `JS` é **case sensitive** e a sintaxe correta é em minúsculo.

```js
var colorButton = document.getElementById('colorButton');

colorButton.onclick = function () {
    console.log('clicked');
    header.className = 'red-text';
};
```

```css
.red-text {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Clique para mudar a cor!</h1>
<input type="button" id="colorButton" value="Clique aqui!"></input>
```