# Como trocar a cor do button quando pressionado?

Tags: android, button

Preciso mudar a cor de um button quando ele é pressionado, como poderia ser feito?

Comment: Veja esse exemplo que fiz em outra pergunta, faz exatamente isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260618/88202

Answer (score 0):

buttoncolor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" /> 
      <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" /> 
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnorm" /> 
  </selector>
```

Agora use assim:

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         b2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever));
    }
});

b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         b1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever));
    }
});
```

[Referência: StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189715/android-button-color-changing-on-onclick)